# Add charges on Organic Structures in Chemfig

Tags: equations, chemfig, chemistry

Essentially I just want to put a charge on a carbon atom, but I don't want to include the "C", using \chemabove almost works however it creates gaps between the bonds.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\setangleincrement{30}
\setatomsep{20pt}

\begin{center}
        \schemestart
        \chemfig{\chemabove{}{\hspace{-15pt}{\textcolor{blue}{+}}}(-[-1]-[-3]H)(-[7])(-[3]N(-[1]R)(-[5]R))}
        \schemestop
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result from code]
[image: What I want to create]

Anyone know a good way to add the charge without the gaps (or the need to add the C atom)?

Compiled using -> latexmk -pdf file.tex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add things afterwards with `\chemmove`. All you need to do is to set some nodes with the `@{<name>}{<content>}` syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
        \schemestart
        \chemfig{(-[-1]@{plus}{}-[-3]H)(-[7])(-[3]N(-[1]R)(-[5]R))}
        \schemestop
\chemmove{
\node at ([xshift=1.5mm]plus) {+};
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My problem is that your code does not produce the output you show. Do I have to do something special when compiling? Anyway, here is some alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
        \schemestart
        \chemfig{R-[:-30](N-[:-90]@{plus}{}(-[:-135])-[:-45]-[:-90]H)-[:30]H}
        \schemestop
\chemmove{
\node[blue,above left=1pt of plus]  {$+$};
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like this perhaps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\definesubmol\nobond{-[3,0.2,,,draw=none]}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \schemestart
        \chemfig{(-[-1]-[6]H)(-[5])(-[2]N(-[1]R)(-[3]R))(!\nobond\textcolor{blue}{\oplus})}
        \schemestop
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: f]